# How to overwrite nn.conv2d

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, overwrite

I want to overwrite nn.conv2d so prepared models such as resnet, alexnet etc. can use it without changing the all nn.conv2ds in the model manually.

```py
from torchvision import models
from torch import nn

class replace_conv2d(nn.Module):
      # other codes

nn.conv2d = replace_conv2d # what I want to do
model = models.resnet18()
```

so resnet18 will use the replace_conv2d class instead of nn.conv2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you could overwrite the modules when they are loaded in. What you can do though is wrap the `nn.Module` with a function that will go through the module tree and replace `nn.Conv2d` with another layer implementation (for example here `nn.Identity`). The only trick is the fact child layers can be identified by compound keys. For example `models.layer1[0].conv2` has keys `"layer1"`, `"0"`, and finally `"conv2"`.

Gather the `nn.Conv2d` and split their compound keys:

```
convs = []
for k, v in model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(v, nn.Conv2d):
        convs.append(k.split('.'))
```

Build a recursive function to get a sub module from a compound key:

```
inspect = lambda m, k: inspect(getattr(m, k[0]), k[1:]) if len(k)>1 else m
```

Finally, you can iterate over the submodules and replace the layer:

```
for k in convs:
    setattr(inspect(model, k), k[-1], nn.Identity())
```

You will see all `nn.Conv2d` layers (whatever their depth) will be replaced:

```
>>> model.layer1[0].conv2
Identity()
```

---

If you want to access the parameters of the conv layer you are about to replace, you can check [its attributes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/nn/modules/conv.py#L103-L112):

```
keys = 'in_channels', 'out_channels', 'kernel_size', \
       'stride', 'padding', 'dilation', 'groups', \
       'bias', 'padding_mode'

for k in convs:
    parent = inspect(model, k)
    conv = getattr(parent, k[-1])
    setattr(parent, k[-1], nn.Conv2d(**{k: getattr(conv,k) for k in keys}))
```

Comment: This method is usefull when there are no need to in_channel, out_channel, kernel_size etc. but I need to get these parameters' values to initialize my conv2d before replace the original conv2d.

Comment: Sure, you can get those by accessing the attributes of the conv layer. Have a look at my edit above.